# yii how to hide a column in case of search in yii grid list

Tags: php, yii

> i have tried using array_filter() but still it does not work for published/unpublished column. Actually i want to hide column having move icon when search fields are not empty

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new InfoCategories('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    $model->del_flg=0;
    $enableSorting = TRUE;
    if (isset($_GET['InfoCategories'])) {
        $model->attributes=$_GET['InfoCategories'];
        if(array_filter($_GET['InfoCategories'])){
            $enableSorting = FALSE;
        }
    }

    $statusList = array("0"=>t("common","UnPublished"), "1"=>t("common","Published"));
    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'statusList'=>$statusList,
        'enableSorting'=> $enableSorting,
    ));
}
```

Comment: we can use strlen as callback function in array_filter()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new InfoCategories('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    $model->del_flg=0;
    $enableSorting = TRUE;
    if (isset($_GET['InfoCategories'])) {
        $model->attributes=$_GET['InfoCategories'];
        if(array_filter($_GET['InfoCategories'], 'strlen')){
            $enableSorting = FALSE;
        }
    }

    $statusList = array("0"=>t("common","UnPublished"), "1"=>t("common","Published"));
    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'statusList'=>$statusList,
        'enableSorting'=> $enableSorting,
    ));
}
```